# How to fork a go project?

Tags: go, github, fork, go-modules

I forked a go project and  used `go get` to install it.

But there is a

```
error: go.mod module declares its path as “x” but was required as “y”
```

How to fix it?

One possible way is to modify `go.mod`,

and change `require "github.com/y"` to `require "github.com/x"`

But this way you cannot contribute code to the source project.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

You can keep using require "github.com/y" in your go.mod require, and add below a replace statement like:

```
require (
  ...
  github.com/y  version
  ...
)

replace github.com/y version => github.com/x your-fork-version
```